# Get data from a directory in worksheet cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have question that my code cant run from the y = Workbooks.Open(source). I want to read the directory from a cell but it does not works. Why?

```
Sub Button4_Click()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook
Dim source As String

source = Cells(14, 6)
Set x = ActiveWorkbook
y = Workbooks.Open(source)

y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:Z").Copy 
Destination:=x.Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A:Z")
y.Close savechanges = False


End Sub
```

Comment: `Set`!!  You have to `Set` objects.  So `Set y = Workbooks.Open(source)`, just like the line before (`Set x = ActiveWorkbook`).

Comment: And then you will have problems because (a) you don't have a line continuation after the `Copy`, so it won't think that the `Destination...` is part of the same statement, and (b) you are missing the colon in `y.Close savechanges:=False`.  (And, I guess, (c) you forgot to re-enable `ScreenUpdating`.)

Comment: Thanks for your help. It is working currrently.

Comment: Is the colon in savechanges important?

Comment: I added a bit to my answer to explain why that colon is **very** important.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the all-important `Set` keyword, which is required to set references to objects.  So

```
y = Workbooks.Open(source)
```

should be

```
Set y = Workbooks.Open(source)
```

---

You also have a few other issues with your code, which should probably look like:

```
Sub Button4_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim x As Workbook
    Dim y As Workbook
    Dim source As String

    'Note - this next line is using whatever worksheet is active in whichever
    ' workbook is active.  This is potentially dangerous.
    source = Cells(14, 6)
    Set x = ActiveWorkbook
    Set y = Workbooks.Open(source)
    'You were missing a line continuation character on this statement
    y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:Z").Copy _
           Destination:=x.Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A:Z")
    'You were missing a colon in the named parameter of this statement
    y.Close savechanges:= False

    'You should reset ScreenUpdating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

Is the `:` in `savechanges:=False` important?  **Yes**.

Your current code `y.Close savechanges = False` is firstly comparing the value of a variable called `savechanges` to the constant `False`.  As you have not declared that variable, nor assigned a value to it, `savechanges` will be assumed to be a numeric zero. Thus you are performing the test `0 = False`. Because VBA treats zero as `False` and -1 as `True`, `savechanges = False` will return `True`.  So that means you are doing the equivalent of `y.Close True` - which is almost certainly the exact opposite of what you intended.

With the `:` included, the syntax is treating `SaveChanges:=False` to be setting the `Close` method's named parameter `SaveChanges` to a value of `False`.

Comment: Dear YowE3K. Thanks for your explanation. I will take note of the colon and make sure it is working.